# Phoenix-Framework : transform, associate and nil check Ecto parent model when creating child model

Tags: mysql, elixir, belongs-to, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm coming to the Phoenix framework from Rails. So far it's been a fairly easy transition. Phoenix is newer, though, and I'm having trouble finding some specific information:

I'm using my Phoenix app as an API service layer.
I want my UI form (and incoming curl requests) to use a `virtual field` to find an associated parent model, and fill the child model's `changeset` with the appropriate attribute. So far, so good:

in my child model:

```
schema "child" do
    field :parent_name, :string, virtual: true
    belongs_to :parent, MyApp.Parent
end
```

`...`

```
before_insert :find_and_fill_parent

    def find_and_fill_parent(changeset) do
        parent = MyApp.Repo.get_by(
                  MyApp.Parent, 
                  parent_name: changeset.changes.parent_name
                 )

        changeset
        |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:parent_id, parent.id)
    end
```

This is where I'm stuck. I do not want to allow the child to be created without a parent. How and where do I `nil` check the parent model? Everything I've tried has either blocked or allowed creation unconditionally, despite conditional statements.
It seems like I need to preload the parent model before the check, since Phoenix is designed to prevent people like me from abusing lazy load. Unfortunately, I don't know what the proper load pattern is in general, so I'm not sure how to apply it here. (I'm using MySQL, if that's relevant)

Hints and tips about where to look and what to look at to help me figure this out are appreciated! Thanks!

**---EDIT---**
Per @Gazler 's advice I have made sure that my child model migration has a reference:

```
create table(:child) do
    add :parent_id, references(:parent)
end
```

I'm still a little lost -- I want to find the `parent` by the parent field `parent_name` (`"Jane Doe"`), make sure the parent model exists, and associate the child using `parent_id` (`1`). I'm not sure how to trigger these actions around using a virtual field.

So, I'm not sure how to structure finding the parent, building the association, and checking the foreign key validation, since the foreign key will never exist in the original params. Thoughts?

Thanks so much.

**---RESOLVED---**
Using @Gazler 's updated answer, I can successfully nil check my parent model in the child controller without a virtual attribute or before_insert.

```
def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do 
    user = Repo.get_by(User, %{name: post_params["name"]})
    if is_nil(user) do
        changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{}, post_params)
    else
        changeset = build(user, :posts) |> Post.changeset(post_params)
    end
    etc
end
```

this validates the incoming parameters exactly like i need! thanks @Gazler!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `before_insert` is probably not the correct place to be doing this.

You are using a `belongs_to` association, however if you include the `has_many` association on the other side then you can use [build/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Model.html#build/3) to fill in the parent id:

```
build(user, :posts)
```

This is just a function that fills in the `post_id` field for the struct - it won't validate that the `user` actually exists.

If you want to ensure that the user exists before creating a post then you can use [foreign_key_constraint/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#foreign_key_constraint/3) on your changeset:

```
cast(comment, params, ~w(user_id), ~w())
|> foreign_key_constraint(:user_id)
```

This will ensure at the database level that the record for the parent exists. You need to have the index in your database which will be created if your migration looked like:

```
create table(:posts) do
  add :user_id, references(:user)
end
```

**EDIT**

There is no need for a virtual attribute. Your controller action should look something like:

```
def create(conn, %{"name" => name, "post" => post_params}) do
  user = Repo.get_by(User, %{name: name})
  changeset = build(user, :posts) |> Post.changeset(post_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, post} -> ...
    {:error, changeset} -> #if constraint is violated then the error will be in the changeset
  end
end
```

Comment: ah - my migration did not include `references(:user)`, I think I was more or less adding the association retroactively on the code side. is there a way to write a change migration to add that association? it didn't seem so...

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, though, i wouldn't have thought about going about this the way you're suggesting; i'll try it out. if necessary i can re-write the database, i'm not super far along yet (clearly )

Comment: Check out http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#alter/2 for modifying a table. If you haven't pushed your migration yet then you can just change the original and rollback/migrate up.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, i appreciate it! i tried running through your suggestions, and i'm still having trouble mapping them to what i'm doing. i have updated the original question

Comment: I have made an edit to the answer, hopefully that will clear things up.

Comment: i understand now, and it works perfectly. thank you so much for answering my question!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you find yourself checking for the user presence often, you should investigate using a plug to fetch your user before the request.

Comment: an excellent and timely suggestion -- i will certainly do so :)